# Does C assignment and parameter passing result in implicit casting, or should we cast explicitly?

Tags: c, casting

Is the any difference between the two following pieces of code?

A:

```
int x = get_some_int();
uint8_t y = x;
```

B:

```
int x = get_some_int();
uint8_t y = (uint8_t) x;
```

Also, what if `y` was a `uint8_t` argument to a function and `x` was passed into it (with and without an explicit cast)?

**EDIT:** Please allow me to rephrase the question: Is it the good practice in C to always explicitly cast variables when assigning or passing to a different type? Or is it good practice to leave this to the compiler? What should be "the default" for the programmer to do?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: It's an implicit type conversion.   But, yes, there are various rules in C that result in implicit conversion of values from one type to another.   Sometimes those conversions are "suspicious"  (e.g. the converted value is not equal to the original) and a compiler may emit warnings when doing some implicit conversions.   The explicit conversion often tells the compiler to shut up - which can also result in bad operations sailing past the compiler.

Comment: An explicit cast is only needed for two reasons. 1) the compiler generates a warning, and you want to silence the warning. 2) You want to communicate to people reading the code that the conversion was intended, not just an oversight on your part. But keep in mind that a conversion from a larger type (e.g. `int`) to a smaller type (e.g. `uint8_t`) can change the value. For example, if `x` is 256, then the value stored in `y` will be 0. So you need to be sure you know what you're doing before you add an explicit cast to the code.

Comment: But there are also some cases where it's common. E.g. `getchar()` returns an `int` so you can check for EOF. After you get past that check, you're likely to assign it to a `char` value, and this should be safe.

Comment: The thing that trips up a lot of people about C is the the "default" is "to do what is required in the circumstances". If you want to follow an iron-clad "rule of thumb", the compiler won't care; it will let you follow it right over a cliff.

Comment: @TomDrake: Because experimenting tells you at most something of what one compiler does. It does not tell you what the rules of the C standard are. Individual C implementations may have stricter warnings than required by the C standard, for example. Also, there are an infinite number of types possible in C, due to composition, but only a finite number of experiments can be conducted, so even experimenting with one implementation cannot guarantee what the complete rules are for that implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not one of casting (it's not required the assignment is a direct conversion to `uint8_t` [C11 Standard - 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p2)), the problem is one of range. `int x;` is a 32-bit signed-integer capable of holding values in the range `-2147483648  to  2147483647`. In contrast `uint8_t y;` is an unsigned 8-bit value capable of holding values `0 - 255`.

You could easily assign a value to `x` that exceeds the range of `y`. So what happens then? If the value of `x` exceeds the range of `y`, the value of `x` is reduced modulo `1 + max_for_type` to fit within `y` [C11 Standard - 6.2.5 Types(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9) So the assignment is equivalent to `y = x % 256;` for values of `x` that exceed the range of `uint8_t`.

So for example is `x = 25306708;` then when `x` is converted to `uint8_t` with `y = x;` `x` is reduced modulo `256` to fit within `y`. (e.g. `y == 84`)

If you want to avoid the silent reduction of value to fit in `y`, then it is up to you to test that the value of `x` will fit in `y` without reduction. You can do that with a simple conditional and the constant defined in `stdint.h`, e.g.

```
    y = x;  /* direct assignment, no cast required */

    if (0 <= x && x <= UINT8_MAX)   /* validate x within the range of uint8_t */
        printf ("int x: %d is in range of uint8_t y: %" PRIu8 "\n", x, y);
    else
        /* handle the error as required */
```

Putting together a short example showing the behavior, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>  /* includes stdint.h */

int main (void) {

    int x;
    uint8_t y;

    fputs ("enter a value: ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d", &x) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer value.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    y = x;  /* direct assignment, no cast required */

    if (0 <= x && x <= UINT8_MAX)   /* validate x within the range of uint8_t */
        printf ("int x: %d is in range of uint8_t y: %" PRIu8 "\n", x, y);
    else 
        printf ("x: %d exceeds range of uint8_t, reduced modulo to y: %"
                PRIu8 "\n", x, y);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/intuint8_t
enter a value: 254
int x: 254 is in range of uint8_t y: 254

$ ./bin/intuint8_t
.enter a value: 256
x: 256 exceeds range of uint8_t, reduced modulo to y: 0

$ ./bin/intuint8_t
enter a value: 25306708
x: 25306708 exceeds range of uint8_t, reduced modulo to y: 84
```

In answer to:

> "Is it the good practice in C to always explicitly cast variables"

*No.* Casting will mask warnings the compiler will generate if what you are doing involves incompatible types. You should cast only rarely and only where explicitly needed as required by a library API, etc..

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

The C 2018 standard says, in clause 6.5.16.1, paragraph 2:

> In *simple assignment* (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

So, yes, conversion happens implicitly. The C standard does not require you to use a cast.

However, only certain operands are allowed. Paragraph 1 says, in large part, that the left and right operands must both be arithmetic types or must have compatible types.<sup>1</sup> So, if the left and right operands do not meet the criteria in paragraph 1, you **must** use a cast to convert the right operand to a type that satisfies the criteria.

That gives us these cases:

- The left and right operands are allowed by the C standard, and the compiler accepts them without complaint: No cast is needed. You can use one if you want to convey some intent to a person reading the code, but casts are not generally recommended, as they can conceal warning and error messages that may help find bugs.
- The left and right operands are allowed by the C standard, but the compiler(s) you are using issue a warning message: A cast is needed if you want to suppress the warning. However, the compiler is trying to tell you something with the warning, such as that the cast may hide an overflow. You should be sure you understand the cause of the warning before you insert a cast.
- The left and right operands are not allowed by the C standard: A cast is needed. Again, you should fully understand the semantics before you insert a cast.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The complete text of paragraph 1 is:

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has arithmetic type;
>
> — the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type compatible with the type of the right;
>
> — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
>
> — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
>
> — the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right is a null pointer constant; or
>
> — the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified `_Bool`, and the right is a pointer.